# script to extract excel data

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with columns that look like these:

```
case 1 case2 control1 control2
aa     ag     ag       ag
aa     aa     tt       tt
tt     tt     ct       cc
```

Could anybody provide me script/tips to extract/highlight rows in an excel sheet in which  two columns have similar values and two other columns have values similar to each other, but different from the first two?  I am on a 64-bit XP that has excel-2007.

Comment: "similar" as in the two columns have the same text content (genotypes, such as aa, cc, tt, gg or two-alphabet combinations of a,c,t and g)

Comment: Have you looked at Excel's conditional highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

if the actual data start in A2, use this formula for [conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-change-find-or-clear-conditional-formats-HP010073939.aspx#BM10):

```
=COUNTIF($B2:$D2;$A2)+COUNTIF($C2:$D2;$B2)+COUNTIF($D2;$C2)=2
```